# Unable to connect to SVN repository from XCode5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am not able to connect to SVN repository from XCode5. It gives me error E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL "xx/xxx/"
I can connect to same repository from Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Can you connect to it from Terminal?

Comment: Yes Nicholas, I am able to connect to SVN from terminal

Comment: Hey found any solution?

Comment: Same here! Did you solve the problem already?